# Redux saga stuck in loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

I using redux-saga for testing and learning, but weird error happend, when i use saga for log out, it show loop, why this happen?

Here is saga code

**Logut**

```
function* logOutSaga(action){
     yield put({type:'LOG_OUT'})
         navigate('Login')
}
export {logOutSaga}
```

**Root**

```
 export function* watchSaga() {
        yield takeLatest(GET_USER_INFO,loginSaga);
        yield takeLatest(LOG_OUT,logOutSaga)
    }
```

**Mainscreen**

```
function MainScreen({navigation, route}) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    function RemoveUser(){
        dispatch(Logout())
    }
    const signInStatus = useSelector((state) => {
        return (state.AuthReducer.isAuth)
    })
    return (
        <View style={styles.ViewStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.TextForm}>Welcome to System</Text>
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                        console.log(signInStatus)
                        RemoveUser()
                    }}
                    style={styles.ButtonLogout}>
                    <Text>Log out</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

export default MainScreen;
```

**Reducer**

```
const initStateAuth = {
    isAuth: false,
    ModalShow:false,
}
const AuthReducer = (state = initStateAuth, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionList.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            {
                return {
                    isAuth: true,
                    ModalShow:true
                };
            }
        case actionList.LOG_OUT:
            console.log("user removed")
            {
            
                return initStateAuth
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

It only happen with Logout, Login function work perfectly, here is a image of what happpend when i use `console.log` in `reducer`

Please help, thank a lot

[image]

Comment: Have you tried switching the code for login and logout  cases in reducer? Just to see if the reducer's case implementation itself is an issue?

Comment: In the saga that is called when you dispatch the LOG_OUT action, you dispatch the LOG_OUT action again, which causes the infinite lopp. `yield takeLatest(LOG_OUT,logOutSaga)` => `yield put({type:'LOG_OUT'})`.

Comment: Yes, that was problem, thank for help